# In emacs, grep "erlang source code" search error

Tags: emacs, erlang

In emacs, I want to search "mnesia" key word in project "gproc" for *.erl source code file. 
The command is "`m-x grep mnesia"`.
But mini buffer show me "`Symbol's function definition is void: pde-compilation-buffer-name`". I don't know how to solve the problem.
emacs 23.3.1+ mac os lion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like something implicitly requires pde (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PerlDevelopEnvironment) without explicitly `(require)`ing it.

Try to put `(require 'pde)` into your `.emacs`.

Comment: The problem was solved. The function is wonderful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have added something to your Emacs init file that does not work.

To find out what it is, first run Emacs without init file and try the command. If this works, open your init file and *eval* parts of it until the command stops working. Alternatively, look for something related to `pde`, as this seems to involved somehow.

Once you find it you have to decide if you want to remove or fix whatever caused the problem. (If you update your answer, somebody here might be able to help you with that as well.)